# Why can't parameter names start with a number?

Tags: powershell

Variable names can be numeric-alpha, why can't parameter names behave this way as well?

[image: Switch parameter starting with a number]

Comment: What if the parameter name was composed solely of digits. How do you distinguish between a parameter and a unary minus applied to an integer?

Comment: Currently, you can't. Why not make parameter names following "--" a special case where the trailing characters are interpreted and compared against the parameter set?  It could get confusing, but it seems worthwhile.  
`invoke-function --1 "arg" --2 -3 -foo "bar" --4oo "6ar"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `first-parameter-char` of the `command-parameter` syntax as specified in the [Powershell Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389) does not allow for it.

```
2.3.4 Parameters
Syntax:

    command-parameter:
        dash   first-parameter-char   parameter-chars   colonopt

    first-parameter-char:
        A Unicode character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, or Lo
        _   (The underscore character U+005F)
        ?
```

You can find a list of unicode character classes [here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt).

Comment: The specification doesn't mention whether this is imposed by convention or technical limitation - I wonder which it is?

Comment: Mostly by convention.  In command mode, the text -1 is treated as a unquoted string token (bare word), where as in expression mode it is tokenized as a number token.  Because the behavior already differs based on context, there is no technical reason it couldn't be a parameter token.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely convention, and is not a purely technical limitation.

```
function f($1) {
    $1
}


# Works positionally
f 1


# Works with splatting
$h = @{"1" = 2}
f @H


# Doesn't work by name
f -1 2
```

It's worth noting that the Language Specification was written after the language itself, so there are probably a few points where it's a little more specific and PowerShell itself is.