# How to add a numeric switch to a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, powershell-cmdlet

I know how to add switch parameters to PowerShell scripts, but the name of the switch is always a (valid) identifier like `-Enable` because the name is generated from the backing PowerShell variable.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
  [switch] $Enable = $false
)
```

Some tools have switches like `-2008`. Normally, one would name the switch `$2008` but this is not a valid identifier.

How can I implement such a switch as a boolean value in PowerShell?
Or in other words: How to specify a different parameter name then the backing variable?

---

**Edit 1**

I wasn't aware of number only variables (which is very strange for a programming language...). Anyhow, I created that example:

```
function foo
{ [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [switch] $2008
  )
  Write-Host "2008=$2008"
}
```

For this code, which is accepted as valid PowerShell, I get a auto completion as wanted. But when providing that parameter, I get this error message:

```
foo : Es wurde kein Positionsparameter gefunden, der das Argument "-2008" akzeptiert.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ foo -2008
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [foo], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,foo
```

Translation: No positional parameter was found, that accepts the argument "-2008".

The purpose of the script is to provide translations / wrappers for command line interfaces.

Here is a set of standardized executables with parameters:

```
vcom.exe -2008 design.vhdl
vsim.exe -2008 design
```

Translation:

```
ghdl.exe -a --std=2008 design.vhdl
ghdl.exe -e --std=2008 design
ghdl.exe -r --std=2008 design
```

I would like to keep the feature of auto completion for parameters, otherwise I could process all remaining parameters and translate them by hand.

Comment: i dont understand, do you want the switch name to be exactly `$true`?

Comment: Normally, you would name the switch `$2008` but this is not a valid identifier. So how to specify a different parameter name then the backing variable?

Comment: While you can use a number as a variable name, it isn't interpreted as a valid parameter name (even when specified as an alias). I don't think this is possible (or particularly sensible).

Comment: @Paebbels `${2008}`

Comment: that was my thought, but it doesn't work for me @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: This can't be allowed because it creates ambiguity with parsing negative integers -- is `-2008` a value for an unnamed parameter or a switch named `2008`? I'm not unhappy PowerShell only allows the former. If these switches make sense in your context, consider just tweaking them so they *are* valid -- like `-Y2008` if it's supposed to be year, `-W2008` if it's supposed to enable a warning, etcetera.

Comment: @4c74356b41 curious, the parser is fine with both the definition and execution but ultimately seems to ignore the presence of `-2008`. Does OP have an example of a cmdlet that has a numeric-only switch?

Comment: funny enough, it works if you splat it so, `$p=@{2008=$true}, function @p`, you don't even need ${2008}, $2008 also works

Comment: @JeroenMostert of course, that makes sense. I'd probably go for a `string` (or `string[]` if values are not mutually exclusive) parameter with a limited `ValidateSet` attribute. You should add an answer btw

Comment: "Some tools have switches like -2008": would be interested to see an example of this. Within PowerShell at least it seems unlikely

Comment: Please see my extended question.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell doesn't support numeric parameters (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19007013/934946)).

Could a validateset be an acceptable solution to your problem ?

Validate set does benefit from the autocompletion feature and this is the next best thing, in my opinion, of what you wanted.

[image: ValidateSet and auto-completion]

Foo & Foos — both are the same, except Foos accept multiple parameters.

```
foo -std 2008
foos -std 2008,2009,2010





    function foo
{ [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [ValidateSet("2008",
                 "2009",
                 "2010",
                 "2011","2012")][INT]$std
  )
  Write-Host "std:$std"
}

function foos
{ [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [ValidateSet("2008",
                 "2009",
                 "2010",
                 "2011","2012")][INT[]]$std
  )
  $std | foreach {Write-Host "std: $_"}
}





foo -std 2008
foos -std 2008,2009,2010
```

Comment: The original program e.g. `vcom` does not have a `-std` switch in front of the version number. More over the `-` is missing. So I think I need to use another solution like a Python script with `ArgParse`.

Comment: If it's a wrapper to the real exe, can't you just call it afterward using &"YourWrappedapp.exe -$std"  so you are effectively using foo -std 2008 to call "YourWrappedApp.exe -2008" ? or am I missing something ?.

Comment: The wrapper (written in PowerShell) shall emulate the interface of `vcom` so it must provide a `-2008` switch. internally it will call `ghdl.exe` with the switch `--std=2008` if `-2008` was set on the wrapper. The purpose is that existing simulator scripts for the `vcom/vlib/vsim` calls can be reused for the GHDL simulator, that uses a different CLI, but offers the same commands (analyze, elaborate, run simulation).